Does asking counterfactual questions about the context/conditions of one's birth presuppose the existence of souls?
If I ask the question "Why was I born in this body and not in another body?" or similar variations such as "Why didn’t I have different parents?" or "Why was I born on this planet and not on another planet?" or "Why wasn’t I born in a different century, period of history, geographical location, or country?", these kinds of questions seem to assume the existence of an "I" representing my personal identity, which could hypothetically be moved around and placed into different bodies, places, times, or circumstances. It seems to me that this idea closely resembles the concept of a soul, which for some reason was attached to this body, but in theory it's conceivable that it could've been attached to a completely different body in another place, at another time, etc.
So my question is: Do these types of questions—which presume a personal identity that could exist in counterfactual scenarios—require the existence of souls to be meaningful? Or is it possible to make sense of such questions without invoking the concept of a soul?

Related questions:

Why am I this particular human being?
Why am I myself rather than someone else?
The vertiginous question: Why am I me and not someone else?
Could "I" become consciousness as someone else in the future?
If my parents hadn't gotten married, who would I be?
How should we understand the teletransportation thought experiment?
If I upload my brain into a computer is it still me?
Am I still the same person as I was yesterday?
What's the difference between cloning and metabolism in terms of affecting personal identity?
Could Napoleon have been born to different parents?
Under physicalism, can my consciousness reappear in a different body?


Conversation in an asylum: "Why are we all here?" "'Cause we ain't all there."

I'm not sure how this differs from the other questions referenced?

@keshlam My question is specifically about the apparent underlying assumption that there is a soul-like personal identity that can be preserved under many counterfactual settings. Whether people who ask these sorts of questions are, perhaps subconsciously, reasoning as if souls (or something soul-like) are real.

I watched Matrix this morning.  It had identity transportation by making phone calls to just the right phone number.

I don't know any way of determining what their reasoning might be other than asking them individually. I decline to guess.

I disagree with the premise: I do not think asking “why was I born [as,in,...] X” presupposes a “soul”.

@Dúthomhas Edited.

I prefer the earlier form before the edit. Now it's obscured by philosophojargon.

Perhaps all such questions and the idea of souls in general are not meaningful?

No, it does not. Of course not. Who led you to believe any such thing?

It presupposes one of two things (possibly both):
Presupposition: Some form of dualism
(but this may not apply to all forms of dualism)
If one holds that there are consciousnesses on the one side and bodies on the other side (in whatever sense), one might wonder why some particular consciousness attached to some particular body.
It may not be a huge challenge for dualism. One might grant that this assignment is arbitrary, or one might already have presupposed e.g. the existence of some deity with some elusive and incomprehensible purpose for every person's life.
The bigger challenge for dualism is in what good reason to think consciousness exists separately (and where and how it exists, and when it comes into existence and ends and how it interacts with the brain), considering that it has such a close, two-way link with our physical brain, which, in every other circumstances, we'd use to infer that one reduces to the other.
Alternative: Reductive physicalism
For reductive physicalism, the answer is trivial: you're "you" because that's what your brain chemistry produces. It's similar to asking why some object produces a particular smell instead of another smell (as in why it generates certain particulates - the actual experience of smell is a subjective experience that varies from one person to the next), or why some object is magnetic and another isn't, or why some object has a particular weight instead of another weight.
It's just a result of the stuff it's made of. Other things are made of different stuff, and they therefore end up being different.
This also challenges our idea of identity. We tend to think of consciousness as a single unit, and that we have "the same" consciousness throughout our lives... even though we recognise that we change - "I was a completely different person back then" is not an uncommon saying. But if consciousness reduces to brain chemistry (which constantly changes), then we can think of it more like a computer. You might always broadly have the same parts, but you could see wildly different things on the screen based on what programs you have installed and what you have running and what's going on in memory, and one computer behaves differently from another because much of that is different and they may have different hardware.
There is of course a lot more to say about the philosophy of mind, and there are other non-dualist, mostly physicalist, views.
Presupposition: It's all about you
If you think that everything exists for your sake, that the entire world was built around you and for you, then one might wonder why it was built with you being born in a particular time and place.
Some people might not lean quite that hard on their self-aggrandizement, but may still have a sense that they have some special significance with respect to reality itself, on a cosmic scale.
But if you recognise that you're simply another one of the 100 billion people who've ever lived, then the question of why you were born as this person and not that person becomes rather meaningless. You may be meaningful to yourself and to those around you, but for reality itself, you're just a grain of sand in a desert. If you ask someone "why is that grain of sand not that other grain of sand instead" they'd just look at you funny and ask if you're okay.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It does not. Phrasing a hypothetical in terms of a counterfactual does not presume the transportability of the "I."
In fact, one of the possible answers is from the perspective of hard determinism: "it could not have been otherwise." No necessity for a soul there.


hard determinism: "it could not have been otherwise." == Since every other metric returns a value of zero, I define a "good day" as a day when I learn something fascinating that makes me think. == Thank you for making December 23, 2024 a good day.


This should be the selected answer

@wahwahwah "This should be the selected answer " - I don't see how. The first paragraph simply asserts the conclusion, without explaining why, whereas the second paragraph is about how someone might hypothetically answer such questions, but my question is about the underlying assumptions of the askers (the people who ask these sorts of questions), not the answerers.

@user80226 and its succinctly explained in this post. You could ask for more context, but this is the correct answer.


"Why wasn’t I born in a different century, geographical location, or country?"

They're all the same question as, "Why is it today instead of April 12th, 1837?"
It was a Wednesday. People were there, and they asked that question.
The situation is made clearer by asking , why is it April 23 2024, instead of some other time?
The question sounds profound today, but it will sound stupid tomorrow. The reason is, it was always a stupid question: the symmetry was broken when you chose to ask it  today, this century, in your country.

these kinds of questions seem to assume the existence of an "I" representing my personal identity,

No, a clever AI  can come up with that question. Mister Data could generate any question that you can ask, because that's what we are, too. We're computers made of nothing but 100 billion discrete switches made of calcium ions, protein, salt, fat, and spices.

which could hypothetically be moved around and placed into different bodies, places, times, or circumstances.

Ooo, snake eyes! I'm sorry sir. Next rollah...
Questions about date and location and context, even when they're intelligent questions, don't have any independent conscious existence.
It just means that different complex systems can come up with the same question. The question doesn't move. Aliens in galaxies long ago and far away asked that question, and they haven't had time to communicate with us.

It seems to me that this idea closely resembles the concept of a soul.

Technically, "Cogito, ergo sum" implies the existence of something — something capable of cogitating well enough to generate that inference.
But not necessarily a soul, with all that implies.
[curtsies]

No.
That I-ness is not unique to a specific neural structure, a specific genetics, one's parents, upbringings, ethnicity, or nationality is -- undeniably true, and is not dependent on one's ontological framework. .
This non-uniqueness is also true of basic features of one's personality, value system, etc.
All of us have "I"s, and the details of our I-ness features are demonstrated to be sufficiently independent of our background details, that it IS reasonable to picture "me" in a different body, with different memories and predilections, but substantially similar to the myself of today in my current body.  This is why empathy and other mind modeling work so well.
Therefore the empathic "there but for good fortune go I" that is behind empathy and compassion morality, and Rawls moral thinking, is also independent of ontology.
That we can then readily extrapolate a mind-transfer, and infer therefore to souls, is a different and further argument, and serves as some degree of evidence in favor of spiritual dualism.  But no, this extrapolation is not necessary for the moral thinking that Rawls and empathy involve.

I think this is a philosophy of language issue: What is the reference of "I" in the question?
In normal conversation, "I" refers to the physical person that's making the statement. There's usually no need to resort to any spiritual "soul", as there's a body that speaks or writes the statement in question. When we talk about the past or future, there's an assumption of continuity involving the person in that body, just like the permanence assumptions regarding other physical objects (your car yesterday is the same as your car today and tomorrow, unless you buy a new one).
But when you ask

Why was I born in this body?

you're clearly not using that definition of "I".
One solution is to simply declare that the question makes no sense, like the Barber Paradox. Since I is defined to be the person in this body, it could not be otherwise. Someone in a different body, or born to different parents, etc. would not be "I".
A more useful solution is to treat "I" as a reference to some set of attributes that uniquely identify you as a person. Given a particular question, you just need to suppose a different set of attributes.
For instance, if the question is

Why was I born in this country?

we can imagine a hypoethetical past where your mother got pregnant with the fetus who would become you in some other country, but didn't move to this country before giving birth. You would still be the same physical person, but have very different experiences.
Or would you even be the same physical person? The mother's experience during pregnancy (especially food intake and prenatal care) has a significant impact on the baby's development. So it's possible that the questions still make no sense, because there's no "essence of I" that persists across all these hypoethical worlds.
Positing the existence of a soul that relates "I" between the real world and these hypothetical worlds just raises more questions. How do you tell which people in different worlds share that ineffable soul? Sometimes we casually throw out statements like "He's who I would have been if I hadn't done X" (e.g. dropped out of school), but we aren't suggesting a soul transfer, merely that we'd have some similar qualities.
These questions remind me of the "mirror universe" episodes of Star Trek. The mirrow universe has a very different history than our own, but somehow there are inhabitants who correspond directly to the main characters in "our" universe. While this is interesting story telling, I don't think really makes sense philosophically -- the correspondence between our Kirk and Mirror Kirk is mostly superficial, we can't really say they're the same person.
It's kind of like asking what would the Challenger disaster have been like if a different company had been contracted to build the Space Shuttles. It might have been named "Challenger" and looked similar, but it would hardly be considered the same ship (and almost certainly wouldn't have exploded on the same day).

That's why I think these sorts of questions would make sense if the "I" refers to a soul (or something like that) which preserves personal identity under all the counterfactual scenarios.

If there were such a thing, I'm not sure how you would you make sense of it. How would anyone identify who has your soul in the hypothetical alternate world? Is there some universe where everything is the same, except your current body doesn't exist and some other body does, so we assume that's the same soul?

I'm still not sure how to make sense of the correspondence of that soul across the real and hypothetical worlds. Each of them knows that they exist, but what makes them the same soul? They're just two random souls in two different worlds.

That's an epistemological question, not an ontological question. In theory, the "I" could be ontologically the same, even if there is not an obvious epistemological method to identify it. That said, if souls are real, each individual soul is a person that knows that they themselves exist. So if we pick soul X and put it under different conditions, X would know they exist because they are conscious and can experience reality. The identification would be trivial for X: "I know that I exist and I'm real".

(sorry I ran out of time to fix a typo.)

What did you change, and is it significant to my response?

The question isn't really whether souls exist, but whether there's a direct correspondence between souls in these different hypothetical worlds, and whether asking the question implies this correspondence. I think nonsense questions don't really imply anything.

"Each of them knows that they exist, but what makes them the same soul? They're just two random souls in two different worlds." - I think this would be equivalent to asking "what makes an electron the same electron when an electron changes location through space-time?". We could even ask counterfactual questions about an electron, say, "if a stronger electromagnetic field had been applied to electron X, making it be located farther away than it actually is right now, would it have been the same electron?".

I tried to touch on that in my answer. In a single world we have notions of physical objects with continuity of identity even as their state changes. I'm the same person when I walk into a different room. There are some sticky issues like Ship of Theseus, though.

But at some point we decide that objects are truly different, like the Challenger built by a different NASA contractor.

There's no hard dividing line, though. Had Boeing management listened to the engineer who warned about O-ring issues, Challenger wouldn't have exploded. But it would be the same spaceship, I think.


These kinds of questions seem to assume the existence of an "I" representing my personal identity, which could hypothetically be moved around and placed into different bodies.

True, in a way. But it's not hypothetical. Lots of people do choose to drastically change their body -- all the way from dying their hair, to liposuction, receiving new kidneys or a new heart, or changing their gender. (Is dying your hair differently "merely superficial", "nothing to do with who someone is"? It may be insulting to persons who do so, when you simply assume this.) Whether or not that means "personal identities" are definite entities -- who knows? We usually don't perceive or are not aware of slow changes in personality, but we know those do occur, and over time they can be rather drastic too. Some people do end up in a psychiatric ward, through no fault of their own.

"But it's not hypothetical" - How about teleportation? If you are teleported from A to B, is your personal identity preserved between A and B, or would it be more accurate to say that you died at A and the person appearing at B is a brand new person? See How should we understand the teletransportation thought experiment?

@user80226: Many possible answers to that have been explored in science fiction. Do some background reading and pick one or several, or write your own story.

Ok, I am having two voices in my head arguing about the answer...
-- "Why was I born here? Why not on a yacht made of solid gold, with a harem of supermodels fanning me with hundred-dollar bills? Because the universe doesn't give a flying f*** about your precious 'I'! It's a cosmic crapshoot, pal. You're here because two horny primates bumped uglies, and boom, here you are, whining about not being born a Rockefeller. Get over yourself!"
-- (Calmly sipping scotch) "Hey, while your colorful imagery is appreciated, allow me to add a touch of intellectual rigor. The question itself is predicated on a false premise. This notion of a detachable 'I,' a soul that could be inserted into various scenarios like a cosmic Mr. Potato Head, is simply unsupported by evidence. The 'I' is a construct, an emergent property of the brain, shaped by the very circumstances the questioner finds so objectionable. To ask 'why' is to imply a design, a purpose. There is no evidence of either. We are, the product of a biological process, not a divine plan."
-- "Exactly! It's like asking, 'Why is this turd this shape, and not shaped like a goddamn unicorn?' Because it's a turd! It doesn't get to choose its shape! And neither do you!"
-- "A rather crude analogy, man, but I believe the essence is captured."
They would both agree that the question is not only meaningless, but also reveals a dangerous tendency to seek solace in supernatural explanations rather than confronting the reality of our existence.

So, just to confirm, is this a yes, or a no? Sounds like you are essentially saying "yes, it presupposes souls".

the question doesn't require a soul to be asked, but it is flawed in its underlying assumptions.

But you said  "a dangerous tendency to seek solace in supernatural explanations", so sounds like you are saying there is an underlying supernaturalist assumption. Which one? Souls? What is the supernaturalist assumption that is flawed?

@user80226 Nice catch!!  Note also the last para meaningless + dangerous Hmmmm... Now that's a strange combo doncha think?

@MissUnderstands, How do you know Groovy 1's gender, and why should it make a difference?

@MichaelHall Yeah, some women in West Virginia were that vulgar, yeah. And no, their gender makes no difference. But mostly, it's men who talk this way —young, less-intelligent men like the ones I grew up with. They're the same people who use the C word
